# Branch Template $name item gives error in experience editor

Tags: sxa, sitecore-client, experience-editor

I am using the below version of Sitecore:
`Sitecore.NET 9.0.1 (rev. 171219)`

When I am trying to access branch template `$item` which also have a presentation that leads error instead of open in editor mode.

[image]

[image]

Anyone face the same issue. Please give your experienced advice to solve this issue.

Answer (score 2):

This is not how you should work with SXA. Use [Page and Partial Designs](https://doc.sitecore.com/developers/sxa/18/sitecore-experience-accelerator/en/designing.html) to share presentation, not branch items. Branch item is not located in any of the Sites, when there is no context of the site, there is no way to determine which Editing Theme should be used. I believe this error has already been fixed and you not hot seen "Object reference..." any more, but one more time - use Page and Partial Designs and never add renderings to items outside the site.

Take a look for example here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0LqngaF5i1U